# Java mistaken with JavaScript

Tags: discussion, tags, not-an-answer

I have found a funny [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173466/i-need-indian-currency-format-like-100000-as-1-00-000-1234-as-1-234). The user who has asked the question tagged it [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) but has attached JavaScript code. The first three answers were about Java solutions and then someone has found that the question is about JavaScript. I edited the question-tag to [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and there comes my doubt.

Shall I flag those answers with Java approach as `not an answer`? Actually they don't even try to answer this question! What is your opinion?

Comment: You mis-interpreted the question.  He knows how to do it in Javascript but not in Java.  He explicitly says "I need this as core java code".  So the [java] tag was correct.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. This topic is totally wrong.

Comment: _"But it is working in only java script, I need this as core java code"_ <-- he wants a Java answer.

Comment: I voted to close current topic as offtopic. Please help me to close this shaming thread.

Comment: Added the *java* tag back.

Comment: @HansPassant I want to distroy this question. It's useless. No need to be agressive just because you don't understand what I wrote. This would wipeout at least 0.000000000001% os all questions and answers at SO!

Comment: @xenteros - you are not getting it here, it's you who has misunderstood. Read it again.

Comment: I understand that I was wrong. I want to close this question as it's just getting offensive. It makes no sense for it to be still open as it's offtopic.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry man, reading the other comments I assumed the 'shaming thread' meant the other question, not this one.

Comment: @McNab at least you. np

Comment: This question will be closed with one of the funniest reasons ever ...

Comment: Of course the current gen spelling of "java SPACE script" helps to make it super-duper confusing. On top of that I've seen plenty of people refer to Java code as "java scripts" already. Not that "shaming" this question, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

The answers were 'valid' at the time and even if they are wrong NOW, they are still actual answers.

You might like to comment each answer to ping the writers that the question has changed in case they wish to change / delete their answers.

If you *really* want to get their attention, **downvote** the *"wrong"* answers with the approriate comment....but that's a personal choice.

Comment: It doesn't matter...even if they are **wrong** answers...they are still answers.

Comment: It's still the wrong flag to use @xenteros

Comment: _"But it is working in only java script, I need this as core java code"_ <-- he wants a Java answer.